# How to match words in an array using Set

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, set

I want to find the words in an array that contain certain characters. However if I try to find them with a for loop, it only iterates once. It should give me the first and the last item from the array below.

```js
arr = ["knighthood", "parental", "fridge", "clingfilm"]

function longest7SegmentWord(arr) {
  newarr = []
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    set = new Set(arr[i].split(""))
    if (set.has("k" || "m" || "v" || "w" || "x") == true) {
      newarr.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return newarr
}

let result = longest7SegmentWord(arr)
console.log(result)
```

But the code returns only an array with one element.
`["knighthood"]`

Comment: You haven't understood the criteria in `has`.

Comment: also the name of your function implies an entirely different purpose, it does not align with the issue you are facing at all

Comment: Also, **declare your variables**.

Comment: If you step through the code with a debugger you'll see that the for-loop variable `i` is _definitely_ incrementing.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because

`"k" || "m" || "v" || "w" || "x"`

is equal to `"k"` so it is only checking for whether the "k" is in the string. (try rearranging the letters). I assume you want to check whether any of them are in the array; you need to do something like `set.has("k") || set.has("m")` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you want to check if has one of that letters you put in `set.has("k" || "m" || "v" || "w" || "x")`

For that you can use regex directly like that:

`if ((/k|m|v|w|x/).exec(arr[i].split("")) != null)`

```js
arr = ["knighthood", "parental", "fridge", "clingfilm"];

function longest7SegmentWord(arr) {
    newarr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        
        if ((/k|m|v|w|x/).exec(arr[i].split("")) != null) { //A nice method is use regex in that case.
            newarr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return newarr;
} 

console.log(longest7SegmentWord(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do something like this `set.has("k" || "m" || "v" || "w" || "x")` in this case. It is running without an error, but will not lead to your expected result.
`||` is the `OR` operator and ill return the first true value. `"x" || "y"` evaluates to "x". It will not even go till "y", since in JS "x" is a truthy value. All strings are.

To further understand, try replacing your code with `set.has("k" && "v" && "g" )`, and you will see that all strings with `g` match.

&& is the AND operator. It has to check for all operands and will return the last one.

To fix, you will have to individually check for your multiple characters using `.has()` with the `||` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.

```
var arr = ["knighthood", "parental", "fridge", "clingfilm"];

function longest7SegmentWord(arr) {
    return arr.filter(x=>{
        return x.includes("k") || x.includes("m") || x.includes("v") || x.includes("W") || x.includes("x")
    })
}

console.log(longest7SegmentWord(arr));
```